# Ida Pro compare constants in same function or not

Tags: ida, functions, script, compare

How do I compare in IDA PRO if constants are located in the same functions or not.. like filter from all constants if I search for 2 constants or more I want to know which function(s) contain all the constants I want to search for, to eliminate searching through all constants with other constants to find matching functions.. (this is how I do it now it's very pain staking)

Constants window looks like this 
[image: constants][image: constants2]

How I do I mark red lines for bad addresses and blue ones for good ones haha

[image: how i do]

Is there any script or even better a plugin that does this job easier for me?

Comment: Which IDA version are you using ? Do I understand correctly that you want to find functions which are using similar constants set ?

Comment: yes I want to find where certain constants have a link together, and best way is if they both in the same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDAPython is the way to go when you want to do such things. I'd say something like that should work:

```
CONST_1 = "1234h"
CONST_2 = "ABCDh"
for func in Functions():
    got_first, got_second = False, False
    func_start = GetFunctionAttr(func,FUNCATTR_START)
    func_end = GetFunctionAttr(func,FUNCATTR_END)
    for ea in Heads(func_start, func_end):
        cur_line = GetDisasm(ea)
        got_first |= CONST_1 in cur_line
        got_second |= CONST_2 in cur_line
        if got_first and got_second:
            print "Found a match at 0x{:08x}".format(func_start)
            break
```

If your binary is really big and it's taking too long, you might think about optimizing the comparaison with operands.